# Can't understand the behaviour of python __del__

Tags: python, del

I have some test code as follow, I was expecting the `__del__` function should be called as if del is invoked.

```
class MyClass(object):
"""docstring for MyClass"""
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        MyClass.count += 1
        print "init instance, total {0}".format(MyClass.count)

    def __del__(self):
        MyClass.count -= 1
        print "del instance, total {0}".format(MyClass.count)

if __name__ = '__main__':
    first_object = MyClass()
    second_object = MyClass()
    # del second_object
```

I am getting the following error:

```
init instance, total 1
init instance, total 2
del instance, total 1
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'" in <bound method MyClass.__del__ of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x100f17d10>> ignored
```

if I enable the following line, it works fine.

```
del second_object
```

Comment: You have probably made some sort of error in paring this code down to produce a small example, since 1.) you have syntax errors (docstring needs to be indented, and you need `== '__main__'`, not `=`; 2.) I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: `count` exists in `self`, not in `MyClass`, I think?

Comment: You're making assumptions about the order in which objects are deleted at shutdown time. Those assumptions aren't well-founded.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error message...seems working fine for me ..!...Just fix indentation and add replace `=` with `==` in your last `if __name__ = '__main__':` expression